# Diferença na aplicação dos algoritmos de Dijkstra e Prim

Tags: grafo

Qual a diferença básica do campo de aplicação dos algoritmos de Dijsktra e de Prim? Quais problemas um deles resolve que os outro não pode resolver?
Tendo, por exemplo, a seguinte situação: é necessário encontrar o menor caminho de trânsito possível que passe por todos os pontos turísticos de uma cidade, sendo que sabe-se a distância entre esses pontos turísticos. Qual seria o melhor algoritmo para resolver esse tipo de problema?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O algoritmo original proposto por Dijkstra serve para achar o menor caminho de um nó inicial até um nó final. Porém o algoritmo de Dijkstra mais utilizado é uma variante que acha o menor caminho de um nó inicial a todos os outros nós do grafo. Em geral este algoritmo será utilizado em problemas de menor caminho (Shortest Path).

A figura a seguir mostra o resultado do algoritmo com a menor distância da raiz até cada nó:

[image: Algoritmo de Dijkstra]

O algoritmo de Prim serve para encontrar a árvore geradora mínima de um grafo. A árvore geradora mínima é o subgrafo conexo com a menor soma do peso das arestas e que contém todos os nós do grafo original. Portanto se o grafo tiver arestas redundantes, elas serão tiradas de modo a obter a soma mínima dos pesos.

Se uma distribuidora de energia elétrica quer ligar todas as casas de um região de modo que os fios percorram a menor distância possível as ligações ideais podem ser determinadas com um algoritmo de Prim. O mesmo pode valer para planejar a localização das fibras óticas em uma rede de internet ou para conectar várias cidades com o mínimo de estradas.

A figura a seguir mostra um grafo completo e sua árvore geradora mínima:

[image: Árvore geradora mínima]

Portanto os dois algoritmos são para finalidades distintas e dificilmente terá um problema onde você terá que optar por utilizar um ou outro.

O problema que você descreveu é o problema do caixeiro viajante com repetição de vértices (Travelling salesman problem with repetition). Este é um problema NP-difícil e colocar a solução dele aqui tornaria a resposta muito grande. Caso você queira a solução deste problema sugiro que abra outra pergunta que eu ficarei feliz em responder.

O algoritmo de Prim não ajuda muito neste problema, pelo menos nunca vi uma solução do TSP utilizando ele. Já o algoritmo de Dijkstra pode ser usado para  determinar o custo mínimo de todos os caminhos dois a dois, que é uma parte da solução do problema, mas geralmente não é utilizado para resolver o TSP sem repetição.