# Algoritmo de Prim e Kruskal

Tags: grafo

Os dois algoritmos servem para gerar uma [Árvore Geradora Mínima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22245/57801) de um Grafo.

No [Prim](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Prim)

- Gera uma árvore única
- Ao longo do algoritmo, o conjunto X sempre é uma árvore

No [Kruskal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Kruskal)

- Gera uma floresta, antes de gerar uma Árvore Geradora Mínima
- Existe garantia de ser apenas uma árvore apenas depois da última iteração

Mas a dúvida maior é:

Qual seria a **Vantagem** e **Desvantagem** entre eles?

---

**Informações complementares**

- Algoritmo de [Dijkstra](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Dijkstra) soluciona o problema do caminho mais curto num
  grafo.
- Algoritmo de **Dijkstra** e **Prim** são quase exatamente iguais, porém no
  Prim você não soma o resultado obtido, mas a execução é igual.
- A utilização desses dois algoritmos são para problemas distintos (não
  são relacionados ao mesmo problema). Um resolve o caminho mais curto enquanto o outro gera uma AGM.

Comment: Se não me engano Kruskal é possível de se fazer distribuído...

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123522/diferen%C3%A7a-na-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-dos-algoritmos-de-dijkstra-e-prim

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Algumas diferenças entre os algoritmos:

- O algoritmo de Prim inicializa com um nó, enquanto o algoritmo de
  Kruskal inicia com uma aresta ordenada.
- No algoritmo de Prim, o grafo deve ser conectado, enquanto o Kruskal pode funcionar em grafos desconectados também.
- A complexidade do algoritmo de Prim em implementações mais comuns para um grafo são por listas de adjacência e por matrizes de adjacência e suas respectivas complexidades `O(|A|log|V|)` e `O(V^2)` no pior caso.
  E o algoritmo de Kruskal possui complexidade de tempo igual a `O(m log n)`, onde m representa o número de arestas e n o número de vértices.

Nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1195932/5327226) do stackoverflow, tem uma comparação interessante:

> Prim's algorithm is significantly faster in the limit when you've got
>   a really dense graph with many more edges than vertices. Kruskal
>   performs better in typical situations (sparse graphs) because it uses
>   simpler data structures.

O algoritmo de Prim é significativamente mais rápido no limite quando você tem um gráfico realmente denso com muitas mais arestas do que vértices. Kruskal funciona melhor em situações típicas (gráficos esparsos) porque usa estruturas de dados mais simples.

Sobre as vantagens e desvantagens:

- Ambos são simples e encontram uma boa solução para o problema, sendo que na maioria das vezes é a solução ótima.
- Se pararmos o algoritmo no meio, no algoritmo de Prim sempre será gerado uma árvore conectada. Já no Kruskal, pode ser uma árvore ou floresta desconectada.

Referências:

- [Algoritmo de Prim](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Prim)
- [Algoritmo de Kruskal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Kruskal)