# O que seria uma árvore e uma floresta?

Tags: terminologia, estrutura-de-dados, árvore

Por vezes aqui, encontrei [aqui no SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%C3%A1rvore), perguntas sobre árvores, grafos e até florestas, nas mais diversas linguagens, mas

- Em programação, o que seria uma árvore? E o que seria uma floresta? Seria uma evolução da árvore, ou um conjunto de árvores?
- Qual a utilidade de ambas?
- Elas poderiam ser comparadas a um `array`?

Talvez uma imagem ajude a compreender melhor este conceito.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22245/57801

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- **Em programação, o que seria uma árvore?**

Na teoria dos grafos, uma árvore é um grafo conexo (existe caminho entre quaisquer dois de seus vértices) e acíclico (não possui ciclos). Seria o mesmo princípio da [Árvore N-ária de Pesquisa](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~r.mello/ine5384/13-MetodosPesquisa2.pdf) ou [Árvore Binária](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_bin%C3%A1ria), **porém na Árvore** cada nó pode ter vários sucessores porém apenas 1 antecessor.

Veja o exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É parecido com a Árvore Binária:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **E o que seria uma floresta?**

Caso o grafo seja acíclico mas não conexo, ele é dito uma floresta. Na [utilização de Prim e Kruskal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215980/57801), se você parar a execução de Kruskal na metade do algoritmo, você pode gerar uma floresta (sub-grafos não conexos), pois a árvore apenas é gerada no final da execução.

- **Qual a utilidade de ambas?**

  Vamos supor que sua cidade precise economizar energia, e que sua cidade possui N ruas, sua função é descobrir quais ruas conseguiria desligar a energia, qual seria a quantidade mínima de ruas com o menor custo possível que precisariam estar ligadas? Isso seria uma utilização da Arvore Geradora mínima.

  Se você gerou uma Floresta ( várias árvores), provavelmente não há uma solução viável.
- **Elas poderiam ser comparadas a um array?**

  Não, está parecido mais com uma Arvore N-Aria. Onde a posição atual possui um "ArrayList" de sucessores e o sucessor possui uma referência ao Pai.

Lendo [esse material](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~r.mello/ine5384/13-MetodosPesquisa2.pdf) de Arvore de Pesquisa consegue verificar uma implementação básica da Árvore, porém é necessário fazer as adequações para a AGM.

Comment: Momento pedantismo matemático: Se você levar em consideração direção de um grafo, DAGs (grafos direcionados acíclicos) podem não ter ciclos, mas mesmo assim não ser árvore. Por exemplo, um grafo bipartido: `A->1, A->2, B->1, B->2`. Não é possível sair de um ponto e voltar para ele, portanto não há ciclos.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado "consideração direção de um grafo" = Grafo Dirigido. Você está falando de [Caminho hamiltoniano](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caminho_hamiltoniano) correto? No seu caso seria uma floresta. Como coloquei na resposta: "Caso o grafo seja acíclico mas não conexo, ele é dito uma floresta"

Comment: Não, caminho hamiltoniano é um problema sobre grafo direcionado. Olhe o exemplo que coloquei no comentário, acíclico porém não arbóreo, grafo bipartido com pelo menos dois elementos em cada partição

Comment: O caso generalizado de grafo leva em consideração a direção. Você obtém um grafo bidirecional a partir de um grafo direcional: se a ligação entre os pontos `a` e `b` for não direcionada, você pode representar isso como duas ligações direcionadas: `a->b` e `b->a`

Comment: As chamadas recursivas da função de Fibonacci podem ser representadas por grafos direcionados acíclicos também. `f3->f2; f3->f1; f2 -> f1; f2-> f0`

Answer (score 6):

Todos são estruturas de dados baseados em grafos. De grosso modo, um grafo é uma estrutura definida por um conjunto de pontos `P` e um conjunto de arestas `A`, onde um elemento `a` do conjunto `A` tem dois atributos, `a.origem` e `a.destino`, sendo que ambos `a.origem` e `a.destino` pertencem ao conjunto `P`.

Um grafo pode ser totalmente conectado (grafo conexo), ou ele pode ter partes totalmente independentes (grafo desconexo). Um grafo desconexo significa que existem pontos `p1` e `p2` tais que não é possível navegar de `p1` e chegar em `p2` pelas arestas definidas em `A`.

Uma árvore é um tipo de grafo conexo em que todo ponto seja destino de apenas uma única origem.

Uma floresta é um grafo possivelmente desconexo tal que, para cada unidade conexa, você tem uma árvore. Uma floresta conexa é uma árvore.

---

Como o @Everson comentou na pergunta, a explicação de grafos e árvores [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22245/57801) estão ótimas, incluindo até mesmo desenhos bem intuitivos.