# Preciso criar uma função que gere um loop dentro do outro só que não tenho definido o tanto de loop(ou seja infinito)

Tags: php

Preciso criar uma função em PHP que gere um loop dentro do outro só que não tenho definido o tanto de loop(ou seja infinito), pq e um sistema tipo pirâmide, ex: eu tenho 1 dependente que têm 4 dependente que por sua vez têm 8 depende que têm mais 2 dependente E por ai vai, até chegar no final e preciso montar essa hierarquia ou família toda.

E cada dependente ao ter dependente, ele fica tendo dependente mas passa a ter sua própria historia a partir do ponto dele onde ele não e pendente, pra ficar mais claro:

```
Meu Pai teve 5 filhos.

desses 5 filhos 1 teve 3 filhos.

e Desses 3 filhos veio mais 4 filhos.
```

e por ai vai, entenderam? todos podem ter quantos filhos forem necessários.

E esses dados têm que estar em uma tabela Mysql de preferência.

o wordpress possui 2 tabelas para fazer isso, eu acho que entendi o processo, mais não consigo ver uma lógica para resolver a questão:

**Tabela1:**

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_terms` (
  `term_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `slug` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `term_group` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;


INSERT INTO `wp_terms` (`term_id`, `name`, `slug`, `term_group`) VALUES
(1, 'Sem categoria', 'sem-categoria', 0),
(2, 'opção pai primeiro', 'pai-primeiro', 0),
(3, 'opção pai segundo', 'pai segundo', 0),
(4, 'opção pai terceiro', 'pai-terceiro', 0),
(5, 'filho do pai terceiro', 'mini-turtles', 0),
(6, 'neto do pai terceiro', 'neto-pai-terceiro', 0);
```

**e a tabela 2:**

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_term_taxonomy` (
  `term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `term_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `taxonomy` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `parent` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;


INSERT INTO `wp_term_taxonomy` (`term_taxonomy_id`, `term_id`, `taxonomy`, `description`, `parent`, `count`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'category', '', 0, 0),
(2, 2, 'category', '', 0, 0),
(3, 3, 'category', '', 0, 0),
(4, 4, 'category', '', 0, 0),
(5, 5, 'category', '', 4, 0),
(6, 6, 'category', '', 5, 0);
```

Bom o que acontece aqui:
Quando usamos qualquer formulário para a inserção de valores em uma tabela salva nas duas, e na segunda tabela fica a ligação com a primeira o campo 'parent'.

resumindo: queria uma função que transformasse os dados na tabela na matriz abaixo:

```
$menu  = array(
                   'casarão'=>array(
                          'mansão',
                          'cluble'
                      ), 
                   'casa'=>array(
                            'casebre'=>array(
                                        'casa da mãe jona'=>array(
                                                'casa do pai joão'=>array(
                                                        'casa do filho josé'=>array(
                                                                'casa do neto josefino'
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                            )
                   ), 
                   'casinha'=>array(
                             'casarinha',
                             'casabela'
                   )
       );
```

Comment: Parece que você precisa de uma função recursiva. Pode dar mais detalhes do seu caso específico? Você já tem a estrutura do banco de dados? Já tem algum código PHP tentando lidar com esse tipo de estrutura?

Comment: sim, tenho a tabela

Comment: agora estou no trabalho, mas quando chegar em casa vou postar a base de dados e tudo mais

Comment: mas vou tentar simplificar: Eu tenho varias opções(pais) em uma determinada tabela e todas essas funções pais elas podem também terem sub-opções filhas e essas sub-opções filhas também podem ter filhos e assim por diante infinitamente. um esquema de categorias igual o do wordpress, no wordpress agente pode cadastrar infinitas categorias e sub-categorias e assim por diante.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o gerador de arrays em php do PHPMyAdmin

Comment: e como eu faço isso meu amigo? ou seja onde fica esse gerador? posso implementa-lo em uma função par me gerar isso dinamicamente?

Comment: Você tem uma [árvore](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216885/64969), certo? Para resgatar uma árvore em uma consulta (MySql 8) aceita [essa solução proposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214625/64969). Veja [isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2425/64969) também