# Dúvida sobre ponteiros em C

Tags: c, característica-linguagem

Então pessoal, eu to com uma dúvida aqui.

O que significa cada uma dessas declarações abaixo?

```
*ponteiro = Valor do ponteiro

 ponteiro = (?)

&ponteiro = Endereço de memória do ponteiro
```

Gostaria que alguém me explicasse o uso do meio, somente o "ponteiro" sem o '*' e '&'

Comment: As respostas dadas explicam o conceito de ponteiro mas seria interessante você colocar algum contexto na sua perguntar para direcionar uma resposta específica para a sua dúvida, como por exemplo, o trecho de código em que você viu essas partes e ficou com dúvida.

Answer (score 4):

Há uma pequena confusão entre os operadores aqui. Mas antes, preciso falar o que é uma variável.

Segundo o autor do livro *Conceitos de Lingaugens de Programação* Robert Sebesta, uma variável é uma região de memória que tem tipo e nome. Simples assim.

Então, o operador de desreferenciamento `&` é aplicável apenas a variáveis. O resultado dele não é o endereço do ponteiro, mas o endereço (um número que aponta para a região de memória) da variável. No caso, `&ponteiro` é o endereço onde está a variável `ponteiro`.

O operador de referenciamento `*` entretanto se aplica a valores. Esse operador vai resgatar o que tem no endereço de memória da variável. Então, para o caso de existir uma variável `ponteiro` que aponta para a primeira casa do vetor `{42,2,10}`, `*ponteiro` retornaria `42`.

Dito isso, agora posso ficar na sua pergunta:

> Gostaria que alguém me explicasse o uso do meio, somente o "ponteiro" sem o '*' e '&'

Isso mais formalmente pode ser entendido como:

> Gostaria que alguém me explicasse o uso de referências, sem ser no caso de usar os operadores de desreferenciamento `&` nem o de referenciamento `*`

Normalmente você precisa disso quando se está usando estruturas compartilhadas. No caso, a estrutura existe e você só tem a referência para ela. Você pode obter essa referência de duas maneiras:

1. se for uma variável e você usar o `&`
2. se for uma região de memória alocada dinamicamente

De modo geral, você só tem diferença entre essas duas formas na criação (dita acima) e na hora de se desfazer dos dados, em que memória dinâmica precisa de um `free` explícito para liberar a memória de volta. Mas não precisa se preocupar além disso, a manipulação geral dos dados é igualzinha, independente da origem da referência.

Então, digamos que você tenha uma [árvore](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216885/64969) usada para armazenar palavras. Digamos que ela é uma árvore binária, em que cada ponto da árvore tem um ponto pai e até dois pontos filhos (chamados criativamente de `esquerdo` e `direito`). A estrutura dessa árvore é algo mais ou menos assim então:

```
struct arvore {
  char *conteudo;
  struct arvore *esquerdo;
  struct arvore *direito;
};
```

Ao adicionar uma palavra na árvore, você vai fazer uma chamada assim:

```
struct arvore* inserir_palavra(struct arvore *raiz, char *palavra);
```

Em algum momento, você vai precisar definir se a palavra vai para o nó que vai morar em `raiz->esquerdo` ou `raiz->direito`. Se for uma árvore de busca, é uma questão de ordem lexicográfica. Então você vai precisar fazer algo assim:

```
int cmp_palavra = strcmp(palavra, raiz->conteudo);
if (cmp_palavra == 0) {
  // a palavra já existe, pode desencanar
  return raiz;
} else if (cmp_palavra < 0) {
  // palavra vem antes, portanto a esquerda
  // se não tiver nada a esquerda, vou inserir o novo ponto na esquerda
  if (raiz->esquerdo == NULL) {
    struct arvore* nodo_palavra = cria_nodo(palavra);
    raiz->esquerdo = nodo_palavra;
    return nodo_palavra;
  } else {
    // bem, não está no ponto atual e o ponto de destino está ocupado, então vou descer nesse destino
    return inserir_palavra(raiz->esquerdo, palavra);
  }
} else {
  // não é igual nem é anterior, então é posterior, está à direita
  // se não tiver nada a direita, vou inserir o novo ponto na direita
  if (raiz->direito == NULL) {
    struct arvore* nodo_palavra = cria_nodo(palavra);
    raiz-> direito = nodo_palavra;
    return nodo_palavra;
  } else {
    // bem, não está no ponto atual e o ponto de destino está ocupado, então vou descer nesse destino
    return inserir_palavra(raiz-> direito, palavra);
  }
}
```

Viu como estou usando apenas o ponteiro propriamente dito ao navegar na árvore? Só me interessavam neles a referência, não precisei navegar dentro do conteúdo da estrutura para isso.

O caso aqui dos ponteiros `direito` e `esquerdo` ilustram o que você gostaria de saber quando usar um ponteiro sem os operadores de referenciamento e de desreferenciamento.

O código mais completo da operação de inserção do exemplo acima segue após esse parágrafo. Para se desfazer da árvore chame a função `liberar_arvore`. Note que estou fazendo um código intrinsicamente *single thread*, então não me culpe se tentar rodar em um programa com operações em paralelo e as coisas começarem a falhar.

```
struct arvore {
  char *conteudo;
  struct arvore *esquerdo;
  struct arvore *direito;
};

char* copia_char_dinamico(char *original) {
  char *copia = calloc(strlen(original) +1, sizeof(char));
  return strcpy(copia, original);
}

struct arvore* cria_nodo(char *palavra) {
  // o calloc já cria com todos os bytes zerados, não tenho então preocupação com estar esquerdo e direito para NULL
  struct arvore *novo_nodo = calloc(1, sizeof(struct arvore));
  novo_nodo->conteudo = copia_char_dinamico(palavra);
  return novo_nodo;
}

struct arvore* inserir_palavra(struct arvore *raiz, char *palavra) {
if (raiz == NULL) {
  return cria_nodo(palavra);
}
int cmp_palavra = strcmp(palavra, raiz->conteudo);
if (cmp_palavra == 0) {
  // a palavra já existe, pode desencanar
  return raiz;
} else if (cmp_palavra < 0) {
  // palavra vem antes, portanto a esquerda
  // se não tiver nada a esquerda, vou inserir o novo ponto na esquerda
  if (raiz->esquerdo == NULL) {
    struct arvore* nodo_palavra = cria_nodo(palavra);
    raiz->esquerdo = nodo_palavra;
    return nodo_palavra;
  } else {
    // bem, não está no ponto atual e o ponto de destino está ocupado, então vou descer nesse destino
    return inserir_palavra(raiz->esquerdo, palavra);
  }
} else {
  // não é igual nem é anterior, então é posterior, está à direita
  // se não tiver nada a direita, vou inserir o novo ponto na direita
  if (raiz->direito == NULL) {
    struct arvore* nodo_palavra = cria_nodo(palavra);
    raiz-> direito = nodo_palavra;
    return nodo_palavra;
  } else {
    // bem, não está no ponto atual e o ponto de destino está ocupado, então vou descer nesse destino
    return inserir_palavra(raiz-> direito, palavra);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O operador `*` quando usado na declaração de uma variável, indica que aquela variável é um ponteiro:

```
// Numa arquitetura 32-bit, sizeof(ptrToShort) trará como resultado 4,
// embora o tipo short tenha tamanho 2, porque ptrToShort é um "ponteiro"
// para uma variável do tipo short, ou seja, ele armazenará o endereço da
// memória onde estará armazenado um valor do tipo short.
short *ptrToShort;

// Mesma coisa, sizeof(ptrToDouble) trará como resultado 4,
// num sistema 32-bit, embora o tipo double tenha tamanho 8.
double *ptrToDouble;
```

Os ponteiros apontam para um endereço na memória, onde está armazenado o valor de alguma variável, por exemplo `ptrToShort == 0x053DC88C`. Nesse caso, `0x053DC88C` é um endereço válido na memória, e deve ser o endereço de início do espaço alocado na memória para uma variável do tipo `short`. Como o tipo `short` ocupa 2 bytes, essa variável `short` estaria usando a memória do endereço `0x053DC88C` ao `0x053DC88D` (`0x053DC88C + 1`).

Mas quando o operador `*` é usado ao lado de uma variável em uma expressão comum, que não seja uma declaração de variável, significa que o programa estará acessando o valor armazenado no endereço de memória para onde o ponteiro está apontando.

E o operador `&` retorna o endereço na memória de uma variável, por isso ele é usado para carregar um valor para um ponteiro. É através do operador `&` que obtemos o endereço de uma variável, para poder armazena-lo em um ponteiro.

Então:

```
short inteiro = 123;
short outroInteiro = 0;
short *ptrToShort = NULL;

// A variável ptrToShort é um ponteiro para tipos short, então ela armazenará
// um endereço da memória, que esteja armazenando um valor do tipo short.
// O operador & retorna o endereço na memória de uma variável, então aqui
// estamos dizendo que ptrToShort agora aponta para o endereço na memória
// da variável inteiro.
// Vamos supor que a variável inteiro esteja alocada no endereço 0x053DC88C
// da memória. A expressão &inteiro irá retornar o valor 0x053DC88C, e a
// variável ptrToShort passará a conter o valor 0x053DC88C, após a linha
// abaixo.
ptrToShort = &inteiro;

// O operador * permite acessar o valor armazenado no endereço apontado
// por um ponteiro, então, o comando abaixo está dizendo: "Pegue o valor
// do tipo short, armazenado no endereço apontado por ptrToShort, e jogue
// na variável outroInteiro". O comando abaixo é equivalente a
// outroInteiro=inteiro, já que *ptrToShort==inteiro.
// Após o comando abaixo outroInteiro terá o valor 123.
outroInteiro = *ptrToShort;

// O operador * permite acessar e manipular o valor armazenado no endereço
// apontado por um ponteiro. Como o ponteiro ptrToShort aponta para o endereço
// da variável inteiro, o comando abaixo é o mesmo que inteiro=321, logo, 
// após o comando abaixo, a variável inteiro terá o seu valor alterado de 123
// para 321, já que *ptrToShort==inteiro.
*ptrToShort = 321;
```

Quanto ao terceiro ponto da sua dúvida:

```
&ponteiro = Endereço de memória do ponteiro
```

esse não é um comando válido, porque `&ponteiro` é um *r-value*, e, portanto, não pode aparecer no lado esquerdo de uma atribuição de valor. Veja mais sobre isso aqui:

> lvalue and rvalue in C language
>   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lvalue-and-rvalue-in-c-language/
>
> C address of an address of a variable
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/9976629/8133067

E, finalmente, respondendo sua dúvida principal:

```
 ponteiro = (?)
```

> *Gostaria que alguém me explicasse o uso do meio, somente o "ponteiro" sem o '*' e '&'*

Levando em consideração que essa variável `ponteiro` seja realmente um ponteiro, ou seja, que tenha sido declarada como `data_type *ponteiro;`, se você jogar um valor assim diretamente nela, espera-se que esse valor seja um endereço válido na memória, como aquele exemplo de endereço `0x053DC88C`:

```
 ponteiro = 0x053DC88C;
```

Se você jogar algum valor que não seja um endereço válido na memória, ao tentar usar esse ponteiro você provavelmente receberá um erro de acesso à memória, ou, se jogar um valor aleatório, que por coincidência seja um endereço válido na memória, o seu ponteiro estará apontando para um endereço aleatório na memória, que pode estar armazenando qualquer informação.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que as outras afirmações estejam incorretas. Não sendo uma declaração de variável:

- `*ponteiro` significaria acesso ao primeiro endereço de memória, onde está armazenado o valor;
- `ponteiro` significaria o valor armazenado na memória;
- e `&ponteiro` criaria um ponteiro, para o ponteiro já existente.

No caso se for declaração de variável:

- `*ponteiro` alocaria memória para armazenar um ponteiro apontando para nulo;
- `ponteiro` alocaria memória para armazenar a variável;
- e `&ponteiro` seria uma instrução inválida.