# Aritmética de ponteiros em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, operadores

Estou com dúvida em um jeito de saber o comprimento de um vetor sem usar `sizeof`:

```
int n = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
```

Sabe-se que:

`arr` é do tipo `int ( * )` e `(&arr + 1)` é do tipo `int ( * )[size]`.

Qual a função do `*`?

É para pegar o valor do endereço `(&arr + 1)` ou para fazer um cast de `int ( * )[size]` para `int ( * )`?

Comment: Veja: [Dúvida sobre ponteiros em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/283067/86952).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O [operador `*`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162956/101) (asterisco ou estrela) sempre é usado para "derreferenciar" um endereço, ou seja, ele pega o valor que está naquele endereço, nada mais que isto, nada tem a ver com *cast*. Pra falar a verdade nem sei do que se trata o resto da pergunta de tão confuso que está.

Ali o [operador `&`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101) retorna uma referência (`arr` já é uma referência), você tem a referência da referência, quando faz o *dereference* fica só com uma referência.

Comment: Desculpe se ficou confuso, vou tentar elaborar melhor.

Comment: quando eu imprimo (&arr + 1) é retornado uma referência na memória que é igual quando eu imprimo *(&arr + 1). A primeira dúvida é por que *(&arr + 1) retorna uma referência na memória se eu estou usando o operador para derreferenciar?

Comment: Por que o operador `&` retorna uma referência (`arr` já é uma referência), você tem a referência da referência, quando faz o *dereference* fica só com uma referência.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Não tinha me atentado a isso. Agora ficou mais claro.