# Soma com vetor e ponteiro em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, soma

**Objetivo:** Somar 7 números digitados pelo usuário que serão armazenados em um vetor, a soma deve ser feita com um ponteiro.

**Problema:** O ponteiro gera um resultado errad, se eu tirar o asterisco da variável ponteiro (o que a torna uma variável normal) o resultado fica correto, mas a variável como ponteiro não da certo.

**Exemplo:** O executável pedirá 7 dígitos, se nos 7 campos eu digitar o número 1 a soma deveria ser 7 mas ao invés disso a soma dada pelo programa é 28.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main() {

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

int vetor[7], i;
int *soma;
soma = 0;

printf("Digite dígito por dígito do seu RU :\n");
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    printf("\n%dº dígito: ", i + 1);
    scanf_s("%d", &vetor[i]);
    soma = soma + vetor[i];
}

printf("Soma dos dígitos do RU: %d\n", soma);

system("pause");
return (0);
}
```

**Tentativas realizadas:** Tentei apontar o vetor para o ponteiro dessa forma: `soma = &vetor[0];` (fora do for) e `soma = &vetor[0 + i];` (dentro do for), mas só deixaram o resultado mais equivocado.

Como faço para essa soma dar certo utilizando um ponteiro ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro é que você está usando um `ponteiro` como se você uma `variável`. O `ponteiro` armazena um endereço. Quando você faz isso:

```
soma = soma + vetor[i];
```

Você está colocando um `valor` ao invés de um `endereço`. Se você quer somar os valores usando `ponteiros` então precisa de um lugar para armazenar essas valores, colocar o `endereço` desse local no `ponteiro` e depois utilizar o `ponteiro` para acessar esse `endereço`. Você pode fazer isso usando uma variável ou fazendo alocação dinâmica de memória.

**Usando uma variável**

```
int vetor[7], i;
int auxiliar; /* variavel auxiliar para armazenar a soma */
int *soma = &auxiliar; /* Colocando o endereco de auxiliar no ponteiro */
*soma = 0; /* Colocando 0 no endereco que soma aponta, que eh a variavel auxiliar */

printf("Digite dígito por dígito do seu RU :\n");
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    printf("\n%dº dígito: ", i + 1);
    scanf_s("%d", &vetor[i]);
    *soma = *soma + vetor[i]; /* Colocando a soma dentro do endereco onde soma aponta */
}

printf("Soma dos dígitos do RU: %d\n", *soma);
```

**Usando alocação de memória**

```
int vetor[7], i;
int *soma = malloc(sizeof *soma); /* Alocando um espaco de memoria para guardar o conteudo */

if (soma == NULL) return 1; /* Verificando se a alocacao foi feita com sucesso */

*soma = 0; /* Colocando 0 no endereco que soma aponta */

printf("Digite dígito por dígito do seu RU :\n");
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    printf("\n%dº dígito: ", i + 1);
    scanf_s("%d", &vetor[i]);
    *soma = *soma + vetor[i]; /* Colocando a soma dentro do endereco onde soma aponta */
}

printf("Soma dos dígitos do RU: %d\n", *soma);

free(soma); /* Liberando espaco alocado */
```

**Veja seu código funcionando:**

[Usando variável](https://ideone.com/1oPR59)

[Usando malloc](https://ideone.com/r2ZHjO)

**Algumas respostas complementares**

[Existe algum problema em atribuir um valor a um ponteiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136535/existe-algum-problema-em-atribuir-um-valor-a-um-ponteiro).

[Qual a diferença entre ponteiro para vetor e ponteiro para variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193507/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-ponteiro-para-vetor-e-ponteiro-para-vari%c3%a1vel?noredirect=1&lq=1).

[O que é indireção?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181032/o-que-%c3%a9-indire%c3%a7%c3%a3o?noredirect=1&lq=1).

[Dúvida sobre ponteiros em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/283067/d%c3%bavida-sobre-ponteiros-em-c/283079#283079).